# How do I call on the values of an array index to use in an equation

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following query that gives me only the value of each row into an array. now I need to write an equation that makes reference to each value listed in the array. for example: 5x $row[0] and 20x $row[1]

First query is the following:

```
$sth2 = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Proveedor_ID) FROM `quehago`.`Natan_Proveedor` WHERE `Proveedor_Ciudad_Sucursal` = '$ciudad' and (Proveedor_Giro_Sucursal LIKE '%Desayuno%') "  );  
$sth2->execute();


$result2 = $sth2->fetchAll();
 print_r($result2);
```

The results are printed as follows:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Proveedor_ID] => 1 [0] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [Proveedor_ID] => 22 [0] => 22 ) )
```

Now, ideally I would like to make a call to array index in [0] as the variable in my first loop, then repeat the query with the value of index [1], etc, etc.

What would be the proper code for that call to index [x] values? Currently 1 and 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but here is what I get out of it. You do some query, get those results and want to do 2 distinct queries with each set of results.

So sounds like you got the first step ok. Now you just do a foreach loop like so.

```
   foreach($your_results as $result){
$sql = 'write your statement'. $result['provider_id'];
//do your query 

 $sql = 'write your other statement'. $result[0];
// do another query 
}
```

your indexes are kind of weird, but whatever it is you just put where you want that value. Let me know if I understood correctly.

Comment: I found a variation of your suggestion and it worked in the same line.